proxmox stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk" after changing /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
Hello fellow server admins,
I have a proxmox hypervisor for my VMs and the file system is raidz1. Today I was wondering if I could install an nvidia card and run 3D Applications so I found a promising tutorial about gpu passthrough here:
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/pci-gpu-passthrough-on-proxmox-ve-8-installation-and-configuration.130218/
Every step worked like a charm until I have entered:
echo "options vfio-pci ids=10de:2489,10de:228b" >> /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
and:

echo "softdep nouveau pre: vfio-pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
echo "softdep nvidia pre: vfio-pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
echo "softdep nvidiafb pre: vfio-pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
echo "softdep nvidia_drm pre: vfio-pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf
echo "softdep drm pre: vfio-pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf

and now booting screen freezes at "Loading initial ramdisk" ,_,
I tried to boot into recovery mode but ... maybe it is really really slow or it froze. The last line at this moment is:

Mounted sys-kernel-config.mount - Kernel Configuration File System

I am pretty sure the problem is due those lines I posted.
So my question:
What happened :D why those 3 lines made the system freeze on bootup and is there any easy fix else then building proxmox from scretch
Thx in advance,
eraikun
Update:
I have followed this tutorial and now am able to see my virtual machines:
https://www.servethehome.com/9-step-calm-and-easy-proxmox-ve-boot-drive-failure-recovery/2/
so my drives look like this:

Still I want to access the system files and not recover the vms :l
any ideas how to access system files of added zfs storage

I would suggest that you take a look at the vendor forum forum.proxmox.com due its specific problem

I just wanted to post the answer which was to open the grub menu and change the mount path right after the initramfs entry.
When I did this I fell into the shell with zfs pool not found or could not be mounted..
Then I force mounted the zfs pool and there I could go into the /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf and deleted the entries!
rebootet afterwards and bum! bootet again :D
Now, since everything works, I will try to make nvidia run again. Let's prey :D
